# regular CW complex and incidence matrices

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, homology, cw-complexes

Suppose that we have a regular  CW-complex $X$. I want to define the incidence matrix of $k$-skeleton of $X$ with respect to the $k-1$ skeleton and I wonder what might go wrong in this case.

If it's not possible to define incidence matrix in this case, are there conditions that we could impose on regular cw complexes that make this notion applicable ?

Comment: You can of course define a matrix like this (e.g. it has a $1$ entry if the boundary of a given $k$ cell intersects a given $k-1$ cell, $0$ otherwise), indeed it makes sense even without the "regular" assumption; but the question is what you want to do with it.

Comment: If you want the incidence matrices to give the boundary maps in a chain complex computing the homology of $X$ then this is certainly possible and can be deduced as a special case of the general method for computing cellular chain complexes described in Section 2.2 of my algebraic topology book.  In particular see the cellular boundary formula on page 140 which uses Proposition 2.20 on page 136.  There is also an old book that develops homology theory from this point of view starting from scratch:  "Homology of Cell Complexes" by G.E.Cooke and R.L.Finney, Princeton Univ. Press 1967.